# If reading the answers to another question solved a problem, does that definitively mean that the first question is a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

If reading the answers to another question solved a problem, does that definitively mean that the first question is a duplicate?

(See my answer below for context)

Answer (score 4):

I think definitively is too strong of a word to use in conjunction with the duplicate process which has a lot of grey in it but, given that qualification, I would answer Yes, based on the answer to [Does the new guidance on duplicate questions suggest closing a question as duplicate, if the original answers the OP's question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217401).

Delving deeper into your original question on Main (I was not involved in the duplicate), and the way I processed it, I readily concede that I should have provided a comment.  However, not all comments are received well, and I do not always have enough time to spend writing them, so I apologize for skipping that step on this one.

As background, we are very upfront in our [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) that there should be only one question asked in each question.  When I encounter one with two distinct, albeit related, questions like this one, I try to decide whether to vote to close it as lacking focus, or whether to edit it to apply the necessary focus.  In this case I did the latter because it appeared that the answer covered your first question without it needing to be asked.

If you really wanted your first question to be asked (and answered) separately then I think there are two options:

- Ask it like you did and risk the community making it a duplicate.  That is what happened, but as a quick fix, so that the question you asked points directly at an answer to it in the duplicate and still open question, you could flag a moderator and ask for them to be merged.  That may well happen in time if left in its current state.
- Ask an improved question that starts by explaining what in the answer to the original question was not adequate to address your first (edited out) question. You could edit your duplicate question to bring it to this state.

Answer (score -1):

No.

First I posted [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/420096/checking-dwg-dxf-file-is-georeferenced) question. It was a two-fold question:

1. Exactly what does it mean that a DWG/DXF is georeferenced
2. How do I check if a DWG/DXF is georeferenced

User PolyGeo edited my question and removed all the parts related to the defition, so only the latter part about checking remained. I tried to look for any kind of comment about why he did so (similar to Wikipedia edit history), but I couldn't find any explanation. My best guess is that he thought the question actually was two questions in one, and that in accordance with the entire concept of Stackexchange, he thought that it was better to reduce it to a more limited scope question.

Before PolyGeo edited my question, user GBG had already submitted an answer which answered both parts.

I thought, that in accordance with the StackExchange concept and goal, which is to build a base of knowledge in the form of Q and A, rather than to immediately help solve users problems, the question about the definition of "georeferenced" files still belongs on GIS.SE. So I added another question about this part: [Exactly what does it mean that CAD file is georeferenced?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/420100/exactly-what-does-it-mean-that-cad-file-is-georeferenced).

Almost immediately a dialogue appeared:

[image]

I know that SE closes duplicates, and since I did not consider this a duplicate, I thought carefully about what to answer (and took the screenshot). Yes, the other post actually did contain an answer that answered my question. Yes, in that sense the other post solved my question. But generally speaking, lots of question posts can be answered by reading through all of SE. But that does not mean that those questions should not be on SE (as long as they are not too similar resulting in too much redundant/overlapping information).

I answered "Yes", thinking/hoping that I was not agreeing to label it a duplicate, but instead simply supplying some information to  the SE algorithms about how the two posts are strongly related because the first post actually did help solve the problem giving rise asking the second question. After all, the word duplicate was not mentioned anywhere.

However, after I clicked Yes, SE did label it Duplicate. I disagree that it should be a duplicate and I don't think the way I answered the question concludes that it is a duplicate.

With this specific case as an example, let me explain further why the answer is "No"

Furthermore, I purposely framed my second question to cover CAD files in general, ie broader than DWG/DXF.

The first post answers the question in my second post, but the part that answers my question does no longer fit well into the question in the first post after that question was edited by PolyGeo. That also means that if someone had a better answer to that question than what GBG submitted (more general than DWG/DXF, more correct, more detailed, better explained, citing examples for comparison, etc.), they are unlikely to submit it anywhere. They can't submit it to my second post because it has been labeled a duplicate, and they can't too well submit it into the first post because they are answering something which is no longer part of the question after it was edited.